# Need to show a component on login button click community

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using lightning Out of the box log in form component to sign in to my community using napili template.On click of the sign in button I need to show a terms and condition component in a modal.The terms and consition modal is opening when I am calling the login form component from a lightning app.However the same is not opening when I am actually login from community.It is always going to the landing page.